# Boolean Modifier on manifold Grid not working

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, modifiers

I created a script which produces a manifold grid inside a object (Picture 1).
If I set the diameter size of the columns under 0.03, the boolean modifier isn't working (Picture 2). Is anyone able to solve this?

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

### Settings ###
thickness = 0.1
distance = 0.5
k_segmentname = "Torus"


# get dimensions & location
objRec = bpy.data.objects[k_segmentname]
(x,y,z) = objRec.dimensions
(xl,yl,zl) = objRec.location

### Helper ###

def joinObjects(obs):
    bpy.ops.object.select_all( action = 'DESELECT' )
    for o in obs:
        o.select = True
    scene.objects.active = obs[0]
    bpy.ops.object.join()


def booleanMod(operation, objA, objB):

    boMoUn = objA.modifiers.new('boUn', 'BOOLEAN')
    boMoUn.object = objB

    if operation == 0:
        boMoUn.operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
    if operation == 1:
        boMoUn.operation = 'UNION'
    if operation == 2:
        boMoUn.operation = 'INTERSECT'

    scene.objects.active = objA
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier='boUn')


def createCube(name, size, strength, location):
    cube = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=size/2, location=location)
    cube = bpy.context.active_object
    cube.name = name

    bpy.ops.object.select_all( action = 'DESELECT' )

    cube_inner_x = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=((size/2)-strength), location=location)
    cube_inner_x = bpy.context.active_object
    cube_inner_x.dimensions[0] = size +2
    booleanMod(0,cube,cube_inner_x)
    cube_inner_x.select = True
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

    cube_inner_y = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=((size/2)-strength), location=location)
    cube_inner_y = bpy.context.active_object
    cube_inner_y.dimensions[1] = size +2
    booleanMod(0,cube,cube_inner_y)
    cube_inner_y.select = True
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

    cube_inner_z = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=((size/2)-strength), location=location)
    cube_inner_z = bpy.context.active_object
    cube_inner_z.dimensions[2] = size +2
    booleanMod(0,cube,cube_inner_z)
    cube_inner_z.select = True
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

    return cube


sLoc_x = xl - (x/2)
sLoc_y = yl - (y/2)
sLoc_z = zl - (z/2)
cube = createCube('Grid', distance, (thickness/2), (sLoc_x,sLoc_y,sLoc_z))

arrayMod = cube.modifiers.new('arrayX', 'ARRAY')
arrayMod.use_merge_vertices = True
arrayMod.use_relative_offset = True
arrayMod.relative_offset_displace[0] = 1
arrayMod.relative_offset_displace[1] = 0
arrayMod.relative_offset_displace[2] = 0
arrayMod.count = x/distance + 1
scene.objects.active = cube
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier='arrayX')

arrayMod = cube.modifiers.new('arrayY', 'ARRAY')
arrayMod.use_merge_vertices = True
arrayMod.use_relative_offset = True
arrayMod.relative_offset_displace[0] = 0
arrayMod.relative_offset_displace[1] = 1
arrayMod.relative_offset_displace[2] = 0
arrayMod.count = y/distance + 1
scene.objects.active = cube
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier='arrayY')

arrayMod = cube.modifiers.new('arrayZ', 'ARRAY')
arrayMod.use_merge_vertices = True
arrayMod.use_relative_offset = True
arrayMod.relative_offset_displace[0] = 0
arrayMod.relative_offset_displace[1] = 0
arrayMod.relative_offset_displace[2] = 1
arrayMod.count = z/distance + 1
scene.objects.active = cube
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier='arrayZ')

booleanMod(2, cube, objRec)
```

[image: Settings: thickness: 0.1]

[image: Settings: thickness: 0.02]